# The confuse of binary orders of writing struct into binary file with fwrite in C

Tags: c, fwrite, storing-data

I am trying to use fwrite to write struct into binary file, but the bytes order of the binary file really confuses me. The struct is as follow:

```
(gdb) p data[0]@10
$1 = {{alphCount = 58, ascii = 97 'a'}, {alphCount = 1, ascii = 10 '\n'}, {alphCount = 31, ascii = 98 'b'}, {alphCount = 1,
    ascii = 10 '\n'}, {alphCount = 20, ascii = 99 'c'}, {alphCount = 1, ascii = 10 '\n'}, {alphCount = 31, ascii = 100 'd'}, {
    alphCount = 1, ascii = 10 '\n'}, {alphCount = 377, ascii = 101 'e'}, {alphCount = 1, ascii = 10 '\n'}}
```

And the result of hexdumping the binary file is as follow:

```
0000000 003a 0000 0161 0000 0a00 001f 0000 0162
0000010 0000 0a00 0014 0000 0163 0000 0a00 001f
0000020 0000 0164 0000 0a00 0179 0000 0165 0000
0000030 0a00                                   
0000032
```

In addition, I have used "__attribute__((packed))" to disable the alignment of struct, so the size of my struct would be 5 bytes.

And the fwrite code is as follow:

```
fwrite(data, 5, 10, stdout);
```

Why the first byte of the file is `"00"` rather than `"3a"`?
In my knowledge, I am using the intel architecture, and the order of storing bytes would be little-endian, I thought the first few bytes of the file would be like `"3a00 0000 61"`, but it actually isn't like what I thought.

Any advise would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: How is this struct declared?

Comment: Like this: `struct dataStruct{
        int alphCount;
        char ascii;
}__attribute__((packed));
typedef struct dataStruct compressData;`

Comment: Thats weird. This data is messed up in many ways.

Comment: You should show single bytes in your hex dump. `003a 0000` is `3a 00 00 00` in plain bytes which is little endian representation of `int`value 58==0x3A. `0161` is `61 01` where the first byte is 0x61 == 97. Then withoud padding the second struct start.

Comment: Yeah, that really confuses me. Actually, this question comes from when I am writing a little project of a OS course. Here is the project link [link](https://github.com/remzi-arpacidusseau/ostep-projects/tree/master/initial-utilities).  The "wzip" part, to be precise. Actually, I have complete the project, passed the test script, and the answer file turns out the same as mine.

Comment: "Why the first byte of the file is "00" rather than "3a"?" --> the first byte **is** 3a.  "003a" is not certainly a listing of bytes in a first byte/second byte order.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I had mixed up, now I got it ,thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing representations:

> Why the first byte of the file is "00" rather than "3a"? In my knowledge, I am using the intel architecture, and the order of storing bytes would be little-endian, I thought the first few bytes of the file would be like "3a00 0000 61", but it actually isn't like what I thought.

Well, yes. But you do not look at plain byte values.
You are looking at 16bit words. For this the byte order has already be taken into account and the first 2 bytes `3a 00` are shown as `003a`.

If you switch your hex dump tool to 32bit values you would probably get `0000003a xxxxxx61` and when you switch to single bytes you will get `3a 00 00 00 61`

Comment: Oh! I had never thought about that! Now I know the problem. Really thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As you say, little-endian byte order is used here, so `003a` is stored as `3a 00`.

To be clear, the first byte is `3a`, and the second `00`.

I find the default format of `hexdump` incredibly poor. Perhaps you should be using `hexdump -C` or `od -t x1` instead of just `hexdump`.

Comment: Yeah, I know what I have mixed up now. And also your advise really helps me out. Thanks!